# Excel VBA Macro Runtime error '1004' for Histogram

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel VBA code that is breaking when I am trying to build a histogram.

It was working completely fine before and now suddenly it is giving me this error. All macros have been enabled from the trust center.

When I debug it is jumping to the following line of code.

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram", ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$A$3597") _
    , ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1"), ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$11"), False, True _
    , True, False
```

I am getting a Run-time error '1004'
Cannot run the macro " . The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

Comment: Do you have the Analysis Tool-Pak add-in enabled?

Comment: Yes, I did have the Analysis Toolpack installed at the time. Also had the Macros enabled. I still don't know what was causing the error on the Macro, but like I said, I disabled it and enabled it again and it worked. I think it is pretty weird if you know the reason please let me know.

Comment: The add-in may not have loaded correctly, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Literally just unchecked and rechecked the analysis tool pack in Excel Add-in's and it worked fine. The world works in mysterious ways I guess.